# Facebook app local development server with no SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, mamp

I'm trying to set up a local mamp development server for my facebook application. 
I've created another application in facebook and pointed it to my localhost. The problem is that obviously my local server has no ssl and facebook now requires a secure url in order for the app to work. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The only "workaround" I know of is to generate a self signed certificate and use that in Apache.

The process (mainly the paths) differ between MacOS X versions, but [this concise guide](http://www.houseofding.com/2008/11/generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-local-development-on-a-mac/) should get you started.